# My layout is not working as shown in designer view

Tags: android

[Link to my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzahZ.png) My layout in design view is not showing as that of design view in emulator
please help. I want the exact layout. I know it's very simple but where I am wrong. I have tried to do with the Linear layout but the same problem persists and yes sorry for my English :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/titleEdtxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:hint="Title"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:inputType="text"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/titleDescrptxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:hint="Description"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/uploadImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="370dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/uploadBtn"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="620dp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="Upload" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/choose_file_Btn"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="220dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="620dp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="choosefile" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share the design which you are trying to render and also the activity code where you are using this layout

Comment: You are using RelativeLayout but i haven't seen _android:layout_below_ or _android:layout_above_ kind of property. Because of that it create issue. Instead you use vertical _LinearLayout_ your problem will be solved. This kind of  `android:layout_marginStart="220dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="620dp"` is worth. That will not fit to other screen devices.

Comment: yes i have shared the link as my repo is low i cant post images here ... @Arshad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You using a lot of fixed dimentions like `android:layout_marginTop="620dp"` which actually varies for different screen sizes . Hence you getting into issues .Try using other more dynamic attributes for setting the layout and check it directly in the **design view** by changing the **phone view setting (third) in the preview panel.**

**Check this for reference :-**

[Relative Layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative)

> **Note:** For better performance and tooling support(to get as in design view), you should instead [build your layout with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="6dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/titleEdtxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

    android:hint="Title"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:inputType="text"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/titleDescrptxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/titleEdtxt"

    android:hint="Description"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/uploadImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="370dp"

    android:layout_below="@id/titleDescrptxt"

    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/uploadBtn"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/uploadImage"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="Upload" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/choose_file_Btn"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/uploadImage"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/uploadImage"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="choosefile" />

   </RelativeLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Well i tried all this things... but problem resists .. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rr_main_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/titleEdtxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:hint="Title"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/titleDescrptxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/titleEdtxt"
            android:hint="Description"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/uploadImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/ll_submit"
        android:layout_below="@id/rr_main_title" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/uploadBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Upload" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/choose_file_Btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="choosefile" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```